# what's the difference between "self-attention mechanism" and "full-connection" layer?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am confused with these two structures. In theory, the output of them are all connected to their input. what magic make 'self-attention mechanism' is more powerful than the full-connection layer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ignoring details like normalization, biases, and such, fully connected networks are fixed-weights:

```
f(x) = (Wx)
```

where `W` is learned in training, and fixed in inference.

Self-attention layers are dynamic, changing the weight as it goes:

```
attn(x) = (Wx)
f(x) = (attn(x) * x)
```

Again this is ignoring a lot of details but there are many different implementations for different applications and you should really check a paper for that.

Comment: i.e. f(x)=((wx)*x)   in self-attention.  Anyway f(x) is a function of x.  So theoretically speaking, multiple FC layers are able to simulate the same behavior of an attention.

Comment: @tom_cat Theoretically speaking, multiple FC can simulate any function.

Comment: is it right to say that, to some extent, attention is a special type of FC, whose weights are dynamically and indirectly determined by some other weights @hkchengrex

Comment: @tom_cat It is a matter of interpretation but I wouldn't say that. I would say both FC and self-attention are cases of "connections" with the weights determined by a fixed or input-related scheme.

Comment: @hkchengrex Could you please explain what you mean with "dynamic, changing the weight as it goes" in this context?